# When there is a mention of time then present perfect changes to simple past..is it applicable in all cases

Tags: present-perfect

Many journalism organizations,over the last three decades,have been working on glossaries to deal with loaded terms...last three decades is time mentioned then why is it in present perfect tense

Comment: They're still working.

Comment: It's not. It's the present perfect continuous construction.

Comment: It is a mistaken notion that the present perfect cannot combine with any time phrase, when the reality is that it cannot combine with a time phrase that excludes the present, such as "last year, a nanosecond|millisecond|second|minute|hour|week|month|year|decade|century|millennium|eon **ago**, yesterday, earlier today, in 1950" and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

A mention of a **duration of time** is acceptable with present perfect forms, with words like **"for"** or **"over"**:

"They have been working there **for/over** the last three decades."

The rule that we should not mention time with present perfect forms applies to time-related words and phrases that indicate **when the event started/occurred**. The exception is when you use the word **"since"**.

"They have been working there in 1982." - **Wrong**

"They have been working there **since** 1982." - **Correct**